# Pull Suggestion out of Google Maps Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm instantiating a google maps Autocomplete box, as such:

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Now, when a user begins typing and the list of suggestions appears, if a user simply presses Enter I want the number one prediction to be used as the search term.

For example, when a user searches: **London**, I want to pull out and send **London, United Kingdom** - simply by the user pressing Enter.

I can pull out that prediction using (with the latest V3.11):

```
autocomplete.gm_accessors_.place.Gc.predictions[0].wg
```

However, this obviously relies on the "compiled" object names, such as `Gc` and `wg` which will change as Google updates their codebase.

What is the correct way of doing this? Is it supported by the Autocomplete API?

**Notice**

Please star this issue on Google to get a solution:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no correct way when using `places.Autocomplete`, it's not implemented so far.

What you can do: the API creates the dropdown, a div with className "`pac-container`", and within that div for each prediction a div with the className "`pac-item`", you may use the text of the first `.pac-item` as value for the input.

A correct way would be to request the [Places Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) , but then you need to create the dropdown on your own.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I hope they find reason for implementing it! Querying the DOM just seems so nasty when the data is already there in the Automplete object - but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You may give them a reason, send a [feature-request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/) . The implementation shouldn't be so complicated as the predicitions are already there, it only takes a method to make them available via the API

Comment: Good idea - Have done so, please vote it up! http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4945&thanks=4945&ts=1361379260